# how to call a method directly instead of button action

Tags: objective-c, methods, action, sender

I want to call the method below directly at application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Currently this action is triggered with a button. How can i call this without the button?

```
- (IBAction)toggleVertical:(id)sender
{
    [splitController toggleSplitOrientation:self];
    [self configureView];
}
```

Comment: Well... By calling it...

Answer (score 2):

Just call it with

```
[self toggleVertical:nil];
```

If the method uses the sender param, you must put inside the reference of your UIButton :

```
[self toggleVertical:self.myButton];
```